# Insert records (result of a stored procedure) into temp table

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

saw different links for this question but could not found one specific to my requirement.

i'm having a temp table which i want to fill with results returned by a stored procedure.
the stored procedure returns multiple columns of which i have to insert specific columns

i tried,

```
create table #temp
(
          [Field1] [numeric](14,5) NULL,
          [Field2] [numeric](14,5) NULL,
          [Field3] [nvarchar](30) NULL
)
insert into #temp
exec sp_name @para1 = par1value,@para2=par2value
```

all this code resides in another stored procedure.
it's giving me error,

`Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.`

how can i insert only the fields interested from multiple fields result set from stored procedure

Answer (score 0):

First you have to make sure that the stored procedure returns the data in the desired format.
Then you can do,

```
INSERT INTO #temp([Field1], [Field2], [Field3])
EXEC sp_name @para1 = par1value, @para2 = par2value
```

To test the SP output, you can simply fire `EXEC sp_name @para1 = par1value, @para2 = par2value` in the query editor.

Comment: If the error is the same as the one you specified in your question, then it clearly states what the problem is.